# How to avoid NVDA announcing "link" in the middle of a phone number?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, nvda

I have a phone number with HTML as such:

```
<a aria-label="Call 1 8 0 0 5 5 5 1 2 1 2 for further questions" href="Tel:18005551212">1-800-555-1212</a>
```

It reads as intended for most screen readers, with one exception being NVDA, which reads something like "link Call 1 8 0 0 5 5 5 1 2 link 1 2 for further questions". The second "link" seems out of place there. What could be causing this and any possible suggestions for a fix?

Comment: Note: I've tried both "tel:" and "Tel:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your simple example with NVDA in both firefox and chrome and I didn't hear the second "link".  Your code sample might be pared down from your original code which has the problem.  Perhaps post a bigger sample from your original code.

As a side note, I understand the `aria-label` with the spaces between the numbers to force the screen reader to announce the phone as separate digits but that causes a problem for braille users.  They will read a bunch of spaces in the phone number and it will be more difficult to read.  It's best to let the screen reader decide how to pronounce a phone number and then the user can adjust their settings to have it read in the style they want it.

When I try this with NVDA in both chrome and firefox, it reads the phone number like you'd expect.

```
<a aria-label="Call 1-800-555-1212 for further questions" href="Tel:18005551212">1-800-555-1212</a>
```

In fact, it reads it **better** than your example because there are slight pauses between "eight hundred" and "five five five" and "one two one two" because of the dashes.  In your example, I hear the string of digits as one long string with no brief pauses.